# how to fix jquery Mobile fixed footer while editing page content?

Tags: css, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I m making a mobile app using phonegap and `jquery` Mobile.

following is my code for `footer`

```
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
       <h1>Some Footer Text</h1>
   </div>
```

I have mentioned `position` as `fixed` still `footer` disappears when i click on any text box to enter data. I need to scroll down to find the button. 
Can't i have `footer` even if  i'm editing in text box or any where else?
Please help me i new to both jquery mobile and phonegap.

Comment: Try adding this to javascript: $("[data-role=footer]").toolbar({ tapToggle: false });

Comment: no, i used this code in document.ready in my html page

Comment: What platform are you encountering this issue on? Android/iOS/Windows?

Answer (score 0):

use data-hide-during-focus="" this in footer tag

```
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
           <h1>Some Footer Text</h1>
      </div>
```